# Aggregate function to multiply all values

Tags: sql, oracle

For example I have data like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

How can I multiply each row? Is there function similar to  `SUM()`, so that the answer will be 120 at this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a technique described here in [**this blog**](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/row-data-multiplication-in-oracle/):

Basically you take the natural log of `SUM` and then do an exponential (`e^x`)

```
SELECT EXP (SUM (LN (col))) as product from t;
```

Since the output of this would be a floating point, you may do a `FLOOR`

```
FLOOR( EXP (SUM (LN (col))) )
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=220dc3b84ddd86f4990aea35141949a6)

**Note**: I've just found  that this would fail if one of the rows has `0`. so you should use a separate condition or a `with` clause that if one of them is zero the product should be zero.

Comment: Negative input values would also cause this to fail.

Comment: @Richard : Yes, for negative numbers,  the bloggers have provided a fix.

Answer (score 2):

This is rarely used, but oracle lets you define your custom aggregate functions.
All you have to do is create a type that implements ODCIAggregate methods and then create function that uses this type.

There is an example in [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm), see section 'Example 11-12 How to Create and Use a User-Defined Aggregate Function'.

I've basically copied the example and changed few lines:

```
create or replace type AGGR_MUL_TST as object
(
  total number,
  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(ctx IN OUT AGGR_MUL_TST) 
  return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT AGGR_MUL_TST, 
                                       value IN number) 
  return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN AGGR_MUL_TST, 
                                         returnValue OUT number, flags IN number) 
  return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT AGGR_MUL_TST, 
                                     ctx2 IN AGGR_MUL_TST) 
  return number
);


create or replace type body AGGR_MUL_TST is
   static function ODCIAGGREGATEINITIALIZE(ctx in out AGGR_MUL_TST)
   return number is
   begin
      ctx := AGGR_MUL_TST(1);
      return ODCIConst.Success;
   end;

   member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self in out AGGR_MUL_TST,
                                        value in number)
   return number is
   begin
      self.total := self.total * value;
      return ODCIConst.Success;
   end;

   member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self in AGGR_MUL_TST,
                                          returnValue out number,
                                          flags in number
                                         )
   return number is
   begin
      returnValue := self.total;
      return ODCIConst.Success;
   end;

   member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self in out AGGR_MUL_TST,
                                      ctx2 IN AGGR_MUL_TST
                                     )
   return number is
   begin
     self.total := self.total * ctx2.total;
  end;
end;
/
create or replace function AGGR_MUL(input number) return number parallel_enable aggregate using AGGR_MUL_TST;
/
```

Now you can use it in any query like a regular aggregate function:

```
with nums as (
   select 1 x, 2 y from dual union all
   select 2 x, 2 y from dual union all
   select 3 x,  2 y from dual union all
   select 4 x,  3 y from dual union all
   select -5 x, 3 y from dual
)
select aggr_mul(x)
  from nums
```

And even with group by:

```
with nums as (
   select 1 x, 2 y from dual union all
   select 2 x, 2 y from dual union all
   select 3 x,  2 y from dual union all
   select 4 x,  3 y from dual union all
   select -5 x, 3 y from dual
)
select y,
       aggr_mul(x)
  from nums
group by y
```

Answer (score 2):

The general solution is a bit more complex -- handling zero and negative numbers.

```
select (exp(sum(ln(abs(nullif(col, 0))))) *
        (1 - 2 * mod(sum(case when col < 0 then 1 when col = 0 then 0.5 else 0 end), 2)
       ) as product
```

- The `nullif()` handles `0`, so `ln()` does not return an error.
- The `abs()` handles negative numbers, so `ln()`does not return an error.
- The `case` expression handles the sign on the result and also returns zero if any value is zero.